# Same sizes on screen and on print?

Tags: html, css, printing

Not sure about Macs, but if I create an HTML document with one of the following CSS

```
/* A4 paper size, standard "office" paper size in Europe,
 * landscape orientation */
html { width: 297mm; height: 210mm; outline: 1px dashed red; }
```

```
/* "Letter" paper size, standard "office" paper size in USA,
 * landscape orientation */
html { width: 11in; height: 8.5in; outline: 1px dashed red; }
```

and then take a real paper and put in on screen of a PC with Windows or Linux, the page on the screen will be larger than the physical one. Yes, I know, this is because of screen DPI (PPI).

But is it possible to make HTML show the same exact sizes as they will be on print?

Comment: Use a pdf for that. That's not what html was made for.

Comment: check this https://github.com/delight-im/HTML-Sheets-of-Paper